# In Git how do make my current branch master or merge it to master but force it to accept all my changes

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a project where I created a new branch (i.e. not master, but off master) about 6 months ago. I forgot and now I want to merge the new branch with Master, but I want master to accept all my changes, in from my new branch, with any conflicts.

Master should just take, shut up and accept everything.

Here is my current stat

```
Master > 6monthBranch > hotfix
```

I want to end up with

```
Master6monthBranch > hotfix
```

Where Master6monthBranch is really Master but with all 6monthBranch merged in (without conflicts).

Is there some command I can run to give you any more helpful information?

Comment: just create an other branch named `newa` of `6monthBranch`, check it out, then merge in `master` branch into it, with manual editing of the files, commit changes, then switch to `master` branch, and `git merge newa`. It'll merge silently

Comment: But I don't want to do any manual editing. I just want 6monthBranch to be the master, as master has some old code and 6monthBranch is currently what is used in production.

Comment: How the pc detect properly merges what to remove, what to add? It is the work for human being

Comment: The PC doesn't I want a merge that makes 6monthBranch as the master. I don't care anything about the current Master anymore, its trash. Just want to keep it around for history purposes.

Comment: will, you don't really need to merge the `master` into the `6monthBranch` branch, if so, just rename the branches with `git branch -m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your new branch to be the new master, run

```
git checkout 6monthBranch
git merge -s ours master

# if you want the merged branch be called master, then
git checkout master
git merge 6monthBranch
```

the merged branch will be **exactly** `6monthBranch`, actually it just mark the former `master` branch as a parent of merged branch but do nothing in file level.

Or if there is something **you really need** which is placed in `master` but not in `6monthBranch`, run

```
git checkout 6monthBranch
git merge -X ours master
```

where merge strategy `-X ours` will automatically resolve all conflict (by preferring contents in `6monthBranch` on no condition), and it will not bother you.